# CAGradientLayer doesn't work on UITableView backgroundColor

Tags: uitableview, ios7, background-color, cagradientlayer

I'd like to have gradient background color behind of a table view, which has transparent navigation bar.

Codes as following, but gradient color doesn't show up.

Tried code part of `CAGradientLayer` in a simple normal `UIViewController`, it does work.

Why it doesn't work in `UITableViewController`?

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage new] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.shadowImage = [UIImage new];
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = YES;

    self.data = @[@"Xrsi", @"Liang", @"La", @"Dn", @"Piao", @"69", @"Sun", @"Mon", @"Xrsi", @"Dn", @"Lan", @"Liang", @"Piao", @"69", @"Sun", @"Mon"];

    UIColor * baseColor = [[UIColor alloc] initWithRed:0.016 green:0.729 blue:0.933 alpha:1.000];

    CGFloat hue;
    CGFloat saturation;
    CGFloat brightness;
    CGFloat alpha;

    self.cellColors = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:baseColor, nil];
    if ([baseColor getHue:&hue saturation:&saturation brightness:&brightness alpha:&alpha]) {
        for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < [self.data count]; i ++) {
            brightness = brightness - 0.025;
            UIColor * newColor = [UIColor colorWithHue:hue saturation:saturation brightness:brightness alpha:alpha];
            [self.cellColors addObject:newColor];
        }
    }

    self.tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone;

    UIColor * bottomColor = [self.cellColors lastObject];
    CAGradientLayer * gradientLayer = [CAGradientLayer layer];
    gradientLayer.frame = self.view.frame;
    gradientLayer.colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:(id)baseColor.CGColor, (id)bottomColor.CGColor, nil];
    [self.view.layer insertSublayer:gradientLayer atIndex:0];

}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    cell.backgroundColor = self.cellColors[indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = self.data[indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

    return cell;
}
```

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Create a plain UIView whose layer is a gradient layer, appropriately configured (it sounds like you already know how to do that).
2. Make that view the table view's `backgroundView`.
3. There is no step 3.

Comment: yes! It works! Why can only `backgroundView` work on `UITableView`?

Comment: It doesn't matter why. They gave you a `backgroundView` for exactly this purpose, so all you have to do is use it. Basically, a table view is a huge complicated set of views and layers; inserting your own layer into that isn't going to work. Use the tools you are given. Don't _fight_ the framework; _learn_ the framework.

Comment: Thank U! But I'm confused about `UITableViewController`'s hierarchy, since it has `self.view`, `self.tableView`, `self.tableView.backgroundView`. Which of them are real if to set properties for a `UITableView`'s background and / or `backgroundColor`?

Comment: For a table view controller, `self.view` and `self.tableView` are the same thing. But the second one is cast to a table view already.

Comment: So these two are smaller than `self.tablView.backgroundView` that's a whole screen size. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: No. They are all the same size. Just look and see; you don't have to ask me. You can ask any of them for their size.